# Looping through multiple dictionaries to create new dictionary from values in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two lists of dictionaries. Both contain an item of data as well as a start and stop timestamp. The first list contains dictionaries representing observations of sequences of text with a start and stop time. It looks like this:

```
list_1 = [
      {'word': 'hey hows it going?', 's1': 1.2, 's2': 3.6},
      {'word': 'um', 's1': 3.7, 's2': 4.2},
      {'word': 'its raining outside today', 's1': 4.3, 's2': 5.0},
      {'word': 'and its really cold', 's1': 5.1, 's2': 6.6},
      {'word': 'dont you think?', 's1': 6.7, 's2': 8.1},
      {'word': 'its awful', 's1': 7.7, 's2': 9.0}
    ]
```

The second list contains dictionaries representing observations of categories with a start and stop time. It looks like this:

```
list_2 = [
  {'category': 0, 's1': 0.0, 's2': 3.8},
  {'category': 1, 's1': 3.9, 's2': 4.9},
  {'category': 1, 's1': 5.0, 's2': 7.2},
  {'category': 0, 's1': 7.3, 's2': 7.6},
  {'category': 1, 's1': 7.7, 's2': 9.0}
]
```

I want to create a new item in the dictionaries for `list_2` using `list_1['word']` values according to the following logic:

- If a value from `list_1['s1']` is greater than a value from `list_2['s1']` AND less than a value from `list_2['s2']`, append all values from `list_1['word']` into the new item, `list_2['word']`.
- If a value from `list_1['s1']` is greater than a value from `list_2['s1']` AND less than a value from `list_2['s2']`, BUT `list_1['s2']` is greater than a value from `list_2['s1']`, append all values from `list_1['word']` into the new item, `list_2['word']` for the NEXT dictionary.

Another way to think about it is as you're looping through list_1 and list_2:

- if the timestamps from `list_1` items fall within the timestamps for a `list_2` item, add the `list_1` words to a new key value pair in `list_2`.
- if timestamps from `list_1` items do not fall within the timestamps for a `list_2` item, for example the words 'start' in `list_2[0]` but 'end' in `list_2[1]` then add the `list_1['words']` from `list_1[0]` to `list_2[1]`.

It should look this this:

```
expected_output =[
   {'category': 0,
      's1': 0.0,
      's2': 3.8,
      'words': 'hey hows it going? um'},
   {'category': 1,
      's1': 3.9,
      's2': 4.9,
      'words': 'its raining outside today'},
   {'category': 1,
      's1': 5.0,
     's2': 7.2,
     'words': 'and its really cold'},
   {'category': 0,
      's1': 7.3,
      's2': 9.0,
      'words': 'dont you think? its awful'}
  ]
```

Comment: both your "lists" have only 1 element which is a dictionary with sequential integer keys starting from 0 (so they are indexed very similarly to a list) is this intended? You have very clear logic outlined, I assume you have code that doesn't work the way you want? could you share what you have so far and explain where it is going wrong?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I see how each is a 1 element list. For simplicity, I can convert to list of dictionaries by removing the sequential integer keys if you would be more efficient. In terms of code, I'm unsure where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original algorithm says "the NEXT" one, are you sure it is what you want?  I tried to implement what you said, but it isn't clear what should happen when a phrase overlaps more than 2 speakers.

A few design notes:

- your data would make more sense if the boundaries were `[a, b)` instead of `[a, b]` - where should 3.65 go?
- it might be more re-usable to storing the values as a list (or determining the order of injection by start time) instead of flattening them to a string with spaces here.  You can always flatten them afterwards

```
START, END = 's1', 's2'

def require_speaker(start, end):
    ''' Return the latest speaker in start <= time <= end '''
    # This should be an interval tree if your data is large
    # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree

    # Exactly one of the first 3 is true, so we could use an `else`,
    # listing all for clarity.
    after = lambda v: v[END] < start
    overlaps = lambda v: start <= v[END] and v[START] <= end
    before = lambda v: end < v[START]
    contained = lambda v: v[START] <= start and end <= v[END]

    take_next = False
    for speaker in list_2:
        if take_next:
            return speaker
        if after(speaker):
            continue
        elif contained(speaker):
            return speaker
        elif overlaps(speaker):
            take_next = True
        elif after(speaker):
            break  # Missed it somehow (can't happen if full coverage)
    raise LookupError('no speaker in range %s - %s' % (start, end))

# Prepare a list for phrases
for speakers in list_2:
    speakers['words'] = []
# Populate phrases for each speaker
for phrase in list_1:
    speaker = require_speaker(phrase[START], phrase[END])
    speaker['words'].append(phrase['word'])
# Convert back to string
for speakers in list_2:
    speakers['words'] = ' '.join(speakers['words'])
```

With your data

```
list_1 = [
      {'word': 'hey hows it going?', 's1': 1.2, 's2': 3.6},
      {'word': 'um', 's1': 3.7, 's2': 4.2},
      {'word': 'its raining outside today', 's1': 4.3, 's2': 5.0},
      {'word': 'and its really cold', 's1': 5.1, 's2': 6.6},
      {'word': 'dont you think?', 's1': 6.7, 's2': 8.1},
      {'word': 'its awful', 's1': 7.7, 's2': 9.0}
    ]

list_2 = [
  {'category': 0, 's1': 0.0, 's2': 3.8},
  {'category': 1, 's1': 3.9, 's2': 4.9},
  {'category': 1, 's1': 5.0, 's2': 7.2},
  {'category': 0, 's1': 7.3, 's2': 7.6},
  {'category': 1, 's1': 7.7, 's2': 9.0}
]
```

You get

```
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(list_2)
[{'category': 0, 's1': 0.0, 's2': 3.8, 'words': 'hey hows it going?'},
 {'category': 1, 's1': 3.9, 's2': 4.9, 'words': 'um'},
 {'category': 1,
  's1': 5.0,
  's2': 7.2,
  'words': 'its raining outside today and its really cold'},
 {'category': 0, 's1': 7.3, 's2': 7.6, 'words': 'dont you think?'},
 {'category': 1, 's1': 7.7, 's2': 9.0, 'words': 'its awful'}]
```

Note that your expected output doesn't match your algorithm:

- "um" (3.7-4.2) should be placed in the 3.9-4.9 range
- "its raining outside today" (4.3-5.0) should be placed in the 5.0-7.2 range
- "dont you think" (6.7-8.1) should be placed in the 7.7-9.0 range